# Minted for XML with Tamil and Diacritics

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, minted

I have a XML file I would like to depict in my thesis, using the package minted and LuaLaTeX. It contains among others, markup language of XML, and words such as பெருந்தேவனார் or koṉṟai. If I use \setmonofont for chosing either Noto Sans Tamil, Gandhari Unicode or Source Code Pro, then only some characters are displayed correctly. The latter workes well, however Tamil is not covered. I would like to use minted as I want to present additionally to the XML file, a lot of code snippets, such as Python, or Antlr4. Is there any monospaced font I could use? Or any other solution? A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, headsepline, footsepline, titlepage = firstiscover]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}{xml}
        <test>பெருந்தேவனார் Kaḷiṟṟiyāainirai</test>
    \end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have never seen a fixed-width Tamil font; it would be very difficult to read. Use a sans font, with `escapeinside` option, e.g.: `\documentclass[a4paper, headsepline, footsepline, titlepage = firstiscover]{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\ftam{Noto Sans Tamil}
\setmonofont{Noto Sans Mono}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{xml}
        <test>|{\ftam பெருந்தேவனார்}| Kaḷiṟṟiyāainirai</test>
    \end{minted}
\end{document}`.

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you!